# Download Mp3 Files (Android)

Tags: java, php, android, html, browser

I have Application play some mp3 files from the internet
and I want to add "Download Button" to download any mp3 file from the internet
I want to download from the browser ,,, not from Application ,,, but if I want to call the browser such as :

---

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.mp3")));

---

the browser going to play this mp3 file :(

I think I can add thing after the link to download directly ,,,, any one can help me ?

Note : if you have a code to download from the App ,,, tell me about it also :)
I'm new in android world :P and I want a simple code to can understand it
thank you all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be better off using the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
You can see example code by Lars Vogel [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)

The relevant bit:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.de/img/lars/LarsVogelArticle7.png"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

Note that DownloadManager is available on API version 9 (Android 2.3, Gingerbread) and upwards.

Comment: sure , the better is DownloadManager :)
but I want to ask you how I can determination the path on SD too ?!

Comment: Use the setDestinationInExternalPublicDir method of the Request object. For example, to save the mp3 file as "song.mp3" in the default MUSIC directory, use request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, "song.mp3");

Comment: Oops !! Forgive me, I forget a small thing ,,, when the download end ,,, how I can open the file path ?

Comment: File musicFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "song.mp3");

Comment: You're give me the path only ,,, I want when the dm end download open this path directly ,,, :D

and you are forgive the :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> :P

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your download.php file

```
 <?php
     $file = $_GET['file'];
     header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
     header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
     header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
     readfile($file);
     exit;
   ?>
```

and then:

```
 Uri.parse("direct_download.php?file=filename.mp3");
```

Comment: vodich I wanna download an mp4 file from youtube like http://r4---sn-u2oxu-f5f6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?.. blah blah.mp4. Tell me if i call it where it will be downloaded and how much code of php i have to change.